# What's the simplest way to compare an enum to a integer value return from a DB

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, enums

I'm pulling some data from a table using LINQ 2 SQL...one of the pieces of data is a value that represents an enumation in my application code.

What is the simplest way to make a comparison between the data returned in LINQ objects and the enumeration in the application code. So for example

```
enum SomeEnum
{
  First
  Second
}
```

then in the method I have

```
Table<LinqObject> objects = dc.GetTable<LinqObject>();

foreach (var item in objects)
{
   // What's the simplest way to do this comparison???
   if (item.SomeNullableInteger == SomeEnum.First) // Note I realise this doesn't work!!!
   {
      // Do something...
   }
}
```

I could do this

```
SomeEnum.First.Equals(item.SomeNullableInteger)
```

or I could store the enumeration names in the database and then i'd be able to do this

```
Enum.GetName(SomeEnum, SomeEnum.First) == item.SomeNullableName
```

is there a better way? The enum only has two items and they're pretty fixed...could maybe have a third or a fourth but will probably never grow beyond that. So having a whole table seems like overkill.

Actually this is a duplicate of [C# int to enum conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502905/c-int-to-enum-conversion)

Comment: I'm voting this gets closed...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work as expected - just cast to the base type.

```
item.SomeNullableInteger == (Int32)SomeEnum.First
```

**UPDATE**

The best and cleanest solution is probably to update your DBML file.

1. Open the DBML file in the designer.
2. Select the enumeration type property of the entity.
3. Open the properties window.
4. Change the field `Type` of the selected property from `System.Int32` to something like `global::SomeNamespace.SomeEnum`. Maybe it will work without the `global` qualifier, but I am not sure.

Now, if the code is regenerated, the property will be of the enumeration type instead of a  integer. If you have nullable properties, you must of course use a nullable enumeration type.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for...this also allows me to use the item.SomeNullableInteger (which is of course no longer an integer but the DB type is an integer) in switch statements. I did look at the the DBML definitions and though about changing the type...but because the enum wasn't in the drop down I didn't change it :-), I'm clearly a library user not a library writer.

Answer (score 4):

According to the official documentation, you could cast your enum as an int to compare.

```
if (item.SomeNullableInteger == (int)SomeEnum.First)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

For code clarity, it might be helpful to declare your enum as

```
enum SomeEnum
{
   First = 1;
   Second = 2;
}
```

Comment: they are actually...just forgot it in the code I wrote for the question :-)

Answer (score 3):

Casting the enum to an int should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You could cast the `Enum` to `int`:

```
if (item.SomeNullableInteger == (int)SomeEnum.First)
{
     // Do something...
}
```

Comment: Checking HasValue is not needed, because the lifted comparisons operator handles this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

to have

```
item.SomeNullableInteger == SomeEnum.First
```

to work:

- be aware that First = 0 & Second = 1 (following the declaration of that enum)
- SomeNullableInteger is of type int
- And of course, SomeNullableInteger = 0 means First for you & SomeNullableInteger = 1 means second.

Comment: Good point, unless you specifically assign the value of the enum.  + 1 for thinking to point that out, though.

Comment: I really wanna know how this compiles.