# C# int to Flag Enum

Tags: c#, enums, bitflags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# int to enum conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502905/c-int-to-enum-conversion)

Is it somehow possible to convert an int to a flag combination enum? So, if

```
[Flags]
public enum Foo {a = 0x80,
                 b = 0x40,
                 c = ...,
                 ...
                 h = 0x1,
                 i = 0};
```

is it OK (or somehow possible) to do

```
Foo fooInstance = (Foo)6;
```

so that `fooInstance` would be 00000110?

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox: the flag part is a different aspect.

Comment: @GertArnold `FlagsAttribute` is AFAIK only used in the `Enum.ToString` method and nothing change in the compiler whenever it's there or not. It's name can't even be found in the language specification document. value -> enum is defined as value -> enum_underlaying_type without any exception. So while the OP didn't know that it's question was a duplicate, it is.

Answer (score 16):

Yes.

That works just fine. Flags attribute or not.