# Confusion with parsing an Enum

Tags: c#, parsing, enums

I am converting a numeric value that is of string type into a corresponding Enum. While I was testing my code, I discovered interesting behavior that has me confused.

Using the code example below, can somebody shed light on why an exception isn't thrown if/when the "s" variable has a value that doesn't match one of the Enum values? Also, how is that the sEnum var can be set to a value that doesn't exist within the definition of the Stooge enum?

```
class Program
{
    enum Stooge
    {
        Unspecified,
        Moe,
        Larry,
        Curly,
        Shemp
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number...");

            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            Stooge sEnum = (Stooge)(int.Parse(s)); //Why doesn't this line throw if s != 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4?

            Console.WriteLine("\r\nYou entered: {0}\r\nEnum String Value: {1}\r\nEnum Int Value: {2}\r\n", s, sEnum.ToString(), (int)sEnum);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was a decision on the part of the people who created .NET. An enum is backed by another value type (`int`, `short`, `byte`, etc), and so it can actually have any value that is valid for those value types.

I personally am not a fan of the way this works, so I made a series of utility methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// Utility methods for enum values. This static type will fail to initialize 
/// (throwing a <see cref="TypeInitializationException"/>) if
/// you try to provide a value that is not an enum.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">An enum type. </typeparam>
public static class EnumUtil<T>
    where T : struct, IConvertible // Try to get as much of a static check as we can.
{
    // The .NET framework doesn't provide a compile-checked
    // way to ensure that a type is an enum, so we have to check when the type
    // is statically invoked.
    static EnumUtil()
    {
        // Throw Exception on static initialization if the given type isn't an enum.
        Require.That(typeof (T).IsEnum, () => typeof(T).FullName + " is not an enum type.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// In the .NET Framework, objects can be cast to enum values which are not
    /// defined for their type. This method provides a simple fail-fast check
    /// that the enum value is defined, and creates a cast at the same time.
    /// Cast the given value as the given enum type.
    /// Throw an exception if the value is not defined for the given enum type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumValue"></param>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidCastException">
    /// If the given value is not a defined value of the enum type.
    /// </exception>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T DefinedCast(object enumValue)

    {
        if (!System.Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), enumValue))
            throw new InvalidCastException(enumValue + " is not a defined value for enum type " +
                                           typeof (T).FullName);
        return (T) enumValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enumValue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T Parse(string enumValue)
    {
        var parsedValue = (T)System.Enum.Parse(typeof (T), enumValue);
        //Require that the parsed value is defined
        Require.That(parsedValue.IsDefined(), 
            () => new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is not a defined value for enum type {1}", 
                enumValue, typeof(T).FullName)));
        return parsedValue;
    }

    public static bool IsDefined(T enumValue)
    {
        return System.Enum.IsDefined(typeof (T), enumValue);
    }

}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDefined<T>(this T enumValue)
        where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        return EnumUtil<T>.IsDefined(enumValue);
    }
}
```

This way, I can say:

```
if(!sEnum.IsDefined()) throw new Exception(...);
```

... or:

```
EnumUtil<Stooge>.Parse(s); // throws an exception if s is not a defined value.
```

### Update

As Brandon Kramer pointed out in the comments, C# 7.3 introduced some new generic types that allow the `where T : struct, IConvertible` above to be replaced with `where T : Enum`, to get better compile-time checking of the Enum-ness of the type being passed in. That way you can get rid of the guard statement in EnumUtil's static constructor.

Comment: `Require.That` also comes from my own library, by the way. You can replace it with `if(!...) throw new Exception(...);`

Comment: I like the Require.That would you share how you did it?

Comment: `parsedValue.IsDefined()` doesn't work for me - `IsDefined()` won't resolve(?) - I'm using `if(!...` if that's relevant.

Comment: @SimonHeffer: When debugging extension methods, I find it useful to start by invoking them directly: `EnumUtil<MyEnumType>.IsDefined(parsedValue)`. Once you do that, the IDE tends to give you more useful error messages. It's possible you're missing a `using` statement or a reference, or that `parsedValue`'s type is not actually an enum.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - I think it may be that I'm on C#5. Maybe using IsDefined as a method on an enum object is not supported yet? (As opposed to the syntax of passing object as parameter. This works:         `public static T Parse(string enumValue)
        {
            var parsedValue = (T)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(T), enumValue);
            if (!IsDefined(parsedValue))
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is not a defined value for enum type {1}",
                    enumValue, typeof(T).FullName));
            return parsedValue;
        }`

Comment: @SimonHeffer: I just realized that I omitted the extension method which makes that syntax work. Check out the `EnumExtensions` class in my edit.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Is there some reason you can't just use `where T : struct, System.Enum` as the constraint to get very good static type checking for enums?

Comment: @BrandonKramer: At the time this was written that wasn't allowed by the language. It was [introduced in C# 7.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-new-generics-constraints-in-c-7-3/). I'll add an update about that, though.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Oh wow, I didn't realize that was such a recent addition!

Answer (score 3):

An enum is just technically an int (or whatever you have defined the enum's underlying type to be).  you can check for a corresponding value in the enum, though with a call to `Enum.IsDefined`.  More info here: [Cast int to enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c/29489#29489)

Answer (score 1):

Enum is really thin wrapper over `int`. Basically it is `int` + static collection of possible values (sort of constants). All the checks are at compile time, type checking etc. But when you actually cast `int` to `enum` runtime doesn't care. So validate your input!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the implementation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892571/275388 to remedy two issues

1. The `DefinedCast(object enumValue)` signature indicates that the code can be used with `string` and `int` types (and also needlessly boxes the later).
2. `Enum.IsDefined`/`Enum.Parse` both allocate an array through `Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))` which actually caused needles slowdown for my use-case - this can be avoided at the expense of caching a map.

Hence I wound up with

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static TEnum DefinedCast<TEnum>(string value)
        where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        if (!MapByString<TEnum>.Instance.TryGetValue(value, out TEnum @enum))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(FormattableString.Invariant($"'{value}' is not a defined value"));
        }

        return @enum;
    }

    public static TEnum DefinedCast<TEnum>(int value)
        where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        if (!MapByInteger<TEnum>.Instance.TryGetValue(value, out TEnum @enum))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(FormattableString.Invariant($"'{value}' is not a defined value"));
        }

        return @enum;
    }

    private static class MapByInteger<TEnum>
        where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        public static readonly Dictionary<int, TEnum> Instance = ((TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))).ToDictionary(e => (int)Convert.ChangeType(e, typeof(int), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }

    private static class MapByString<TEnum>
        where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        public static readonly Dictionary<string, TEnum> Instance = ((TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))).ToDictionary(e => e.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use int.Parse() if you wan't an exception to be thrown in the case the value passed is not parsable. Use int.TryParse() if you wan't to parse a value that might be invalid without an exception to be thrown.

Comment: That's not quite what he's going for. He wants to have an exception thrown if the value is not a defined value for his enum type, regardless of whether it is a valid int value.