# Generics and Enumerations

Tags: .net, generics, enums

How to use(constraint) an `Enumeration` as a `generic` parameter in .NET?

I used somthing like

```
Public Function GetEnumStringValues(Of EType As {Structure, _ 
                   IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable})() As List(Of String)
```

but this is not good.

Answer (score 3):

You can use enum types as generic parameters to a method (for example `List<EType>`, but you cannot *restrict* generic parameters to only be enum types.

However, there are tricks you can use to *almost* guarantee that only enums get used in your methods:

```
public static T ParseEnum<T>(this string enumValue)
    where T : struct, IConvertible
```

See [Converting string back to enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421263/converting-string-back-to-enum/5421315#5421315) for a more full explanation and code samples.

Comment: sorry for my English: "there are tricks you can use to *almost* guarantee", almost, but not totally.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible I am afraid.

It has been [requested](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/Workaround.aspx?FeedbackID=386194) though.

Jon Skeet has a [workaround](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates.aspx) for it.