# Converting string to enum?

Tags: c#

I have the following enum in my class:

```
  public enum InventoryType
    {
        EQUIP = 1,
        USE = 2,
        SETUP = 3,
        ETC = 4,
        CASH = 5,
        EVAN = 6,
        TOTEMS = 7,
        ANDROID = 8,
        BITS = 9,
        MECHANIC = 10,
        HAKU = 11,
        EQUIPPED = -1
    }
```

Now, I have a field:

```
    public InventoryType InventoryType { get; private set; }
```

I load the data from MySql. MySql's column of type has the string that is the InventoryType. How can I convert the string I get to the enum InventoryType?

I tried:

```
this.InventoryType = reader.GetString("type");
```

But of course, that doesn't work, because it's getting a string and required an InventoryType. What can I do to convert it? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string back to enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421263/converting-string-back-to-enum)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c

Answer (score 5):

You can parse it using [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx):

```
InventoryType inventoryType;
if(Enum.TryParse(reader.GetString("type"), out inventoryType))
{
    //use inventoryType
}
else
{
    //not valid
}
```

Comment: You should be able to leave out `<InventoryType>`, since it can be inferred from the `inventoryType` variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Enum.Parse` to parse your string back to Enum value -

```
this.InventoryType = (InventoryType)Enum.Parse(typeof(InventoryType),
                                                 reader.GetString("type"));
```

Also, use `Parse` if you are sure the value will be valid; otherwise use `TryParse`.

Comment: @RohitVats you also missed the `)` after `InventoryType`.

Comment: It may be obvious from the samples, but just in case: Parse will throw an exception if there isn't a match.  TryParse takes an out parameter and returns a bool indicating success or failure.

Comment: @Rob - Indeed. That's how it works. Hope that's obvious. Although mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
this.InventoryType= (InventoryType) Enum.Parse( typeof(InventoryType), reader.GetString("type") );
```

Comment: can't I use at the end of the enum delcartion : string?