# C# enum values are not enforced

Tags: c#, enums

In C#, Using an enum

```
public enum ShoppingCartType
{
    ShoppingCart = 1,
    Wishlist = 2,
}

public class foo
{
    public void bar(int parameter1,ShoppingCartType type)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

The following code compiles and runs peacefully

```
foo.bar(param1,(ShoppingCartType)30);
```

Without the cast, the following code will not even compile

```
foo.bar(param1,30);
```

Why does it make sense? 
The result is the same basically..

[Why does casting int to invalid enum value NOT throw exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413804/why-does-casting-int-to-invalid-enum-value-not-throw-exception)
Reed Copsey's answer explains why the first one works, and why it behaves this way.

But I don't see real difference between the first and second code snippets here, especially the second one seems more intuitive and hints this behavior.

Is there a way to change this behavior (before run time)?

(I'm not looking for a way to enforce the enum at runtime).

Comment: I am assuming it's a method whose second parameter takes a `ShoppingCartType`.

Comment: Edited, hope it is clear now :)

Comment: FYI - The first duplicate explains how to avoid the problem; the second explains why it is allowed to happen in the first place.