# Assigning enum of one type to enum of another type?

Tags: c#, enums, console-application

```
class enum_class
{  
  public static void Main()   
  {       
    Gender Unknown = (int)Season.Winter;
    Console.WriteLine(Unknown);
    Console.WriteLine(Gender.Unknown);
  }
}

public enum Gender
{
   Unknown = 10;
}

public enum Season
{
   Winter = 1;
}
```

In the above code I wish to assign the value of variable  Winter to variable Unknown.
Now   `Console.WriteLine(Unknown);`  gives the expected output i.e. Unknown value is changed from its initial value 10 to 1.

However, `Console.WriteLine(Gender.Unknown);`  prints 10 as its output which was its original value. May I know the reason behind this?!!

Comment: You have created a variable of type `Gender` called `Unknown`, you haven't changed the value of the enum at all

Comment: This question may help (not duplicate) - [Why does casting int to invalid enum value NOT throw exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413804/why-does-casting-int-to-invalid-enum-value-not-throw-exception)

Comment: You seem to have some basic confusion here about what [variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wew5ytx4(v=vs.90).aspx) are versus what [enums](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s1w24dx(v=vs.90).aspx) are.

Answer (score 0):

If we trace your code, we see that in the `Main` method, first you create a variable of `Gender` type (which is an enumeration) named `unknown` which is also equal to integer value of `Season.Winter`, that is 1. Therefore, `Console.WriteLine(Unknown)` will result in 1. In the third line, you call the value of `Gender.Unknown`; value of the enumeration you have defined, which is always 10.

To sum up; first `Unknown` in your code is a variable you created, but the second is `Gender.Unknown` which is a constant enumeration.