# Set custom result code in activity

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Usually with Android, you set an integer result code when setting the result of an activity as shown [here:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int))

`void setResult(int resultCode)`

Xamarin, instead, requires an enum defined as `Android.App.Result`.
This enum has these values:

`Ok,
Canceled,
FirstUser`

**The Problem**

You **cannot** set custom result codes in Xamarin Android. FirstUser is supposed to define the first safe custom result for the user to use. i.e, any integer greater than the value of FirstUser is fine to use as stated [here in the Android docs.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_FIRST_USER)

I am forced to set the result code as this enum type. Is there a way around this? The `OnActivityResult` method also uses this enum.

`protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Android.App.Result resultCode, Intent data)`

Comment: Why did you need set custom result code? Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Yes thank you. I am fairly new to C# and didn't realise the following was the case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413841/5504424

Answer (score 2):

> I am forced to set the result code as this enum type. Is there a way around this?

As you said, we can't custom the result codes. If you need to identify which `Activity`'s `SetResult` method fire the `OnActivityResult()` method in `MainActivity`, here is a workaround:

In `MainActivity`, open `ResultActivity1`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ResultActivity1));
StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

In `ResultActivity1`, set the result:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.PutExtra("name", "ResultActivity1");
SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
Finish();
```

In `MainActivity` `OnActivityResult` method:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(resultCode == Result.Ok)
    {
        if(requestCode == 1)
        {
            var name = data.GetStringExtra("name");
            if (name == "ResultActivity1")
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, name, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: This was my first thought but it turns out that you can just use an invalid cast of the enum.

`int myResultCode = 25432;`


`SetResult((Android.App.Result)myResultCode, ...);`


`protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Android.App.Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if ((int)resultCode == myResultCode) {...}
}`

Comment: @SamLiddle, could you please post the answer so that someone else who have encounter the problem can see the answer? :)