# The correct way of casting an int to an enum

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cast int to Enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c)

I fetch a int value from the database and want to cast the value to an enum variable.  In 99.9% of the cases, the int will match one of the values in the enum declaration

```
public enum eOrderType {
    Submitted = 1,
    Ordered = 2,
    InReview = 3,
    Sold = 4,
    ...
}

eOrderType orderType = (eOrderType) FetchIntFromDb();
```

In the edge case, the value will not match (whether it's corruption of data or someone manually going in and messing with the data).

I could use a switch statement and catch the `default` and fix the situation, but it feels wrong.  There has to be a more elegant solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen the other [Cast int to Enum Questions](http://www.google.com/search?q=cast+int+to+enum+site:stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: A general comment about using enums: Make sure you always include a default 0 value `public enum eOrderType { None = 0, Submitted = 1, ... }`

Comment: I think this is a slightly different question than the 'Cast int to Enum' question. As it happens, the second highest voted answer to that question is also a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
int value = FetchIntFromDb();
bool ok = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(eOrderType)).Cast<int>().Contains(value);
```

or rather I would cache the GetValues() results in a static variable and use it over and over gain.

Comment: That was my initial answer (basically), until I realised that there already is a method in the Enum class that does that... ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `IsDefined` method to check if a value is among the defined values:

```
bool defined = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(eOrderType), orderType);
```