# Fastest way to get last significant bit position in a ulong (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, bit-manipulation, bit

What is the fastest(or at least very fast) way to get first set(1) bit position from least significant bit (LSB) to the most significant bit (MSB) in a ulong (C#)? 
For `ulong i = 18;` *(10010)* that would be 2(or 1 if we are counting position from 0).

*MS C++ compiler has  [_BitScanForward64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfd9z0bb.aspx) Intrinsics  for this task, but C# compiler doesn't have analogue.*

Comment: Can you point to something that defines "last significant bit position" as you mean it? Are you referring to the "2" position (next to last bit) because it has a value of 1, but for 10011 the last significant bit would be 1, and for 10100 it would be 4?

Comment: Probably binary search concept with modulo will help.

Comment: This solution is written in C++, but it should be adaptable to C# and is only a couple of operations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/757266/116614.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/31374628/116614

Comment: [This is the fastest way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd.aspx).  Takes one cpu cycle, can't make it faster than that.  Everything is possible, nothing is simple.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, thank you.. I know about  C++  _BitScanReverse. Unfortunataly C# compiler doesn't provide such intrinsics AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have measured perfomance of all answers.

The winner is not present here classic De Bruijn sequence approach.

```
    private const ulong DeBruijnSequence = 0x37E84A99DAE458F;

    private static readonly int[] MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition =
    {
        0, 1, 17, 2, 18, 50, 3, 57,
        47, 19, 22, 51, 29, 4, 33, 58,
        15, 48, 20, 27, 25, 23, 52, 41,
        54, 30, 38, 5, 43, 34, 59, 8,
        63, 16, 49, 56, 46, 21, 28, 32,
        14, 26, 24, 40, 53, 37, 42, 7,
        62, 55, 45, 31, 13, 39, 36, 6,
        61, 44, 12, 35, 60, 11, 10, 9,
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Search the mask data from least significant bit (LSB) to the most significant bit (MSB) for a set bit (1)
    /// using De Bruijn sequence approach. Warning: Will return zero for b = 0.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="b">Target number.</param>
    /// <returns>Zero-based position of LSB (from right to left).</returns>
    private static int BitScanForward(ulong b)
    {
        Debug.Assert(b > 0, "Target number should not be zero");
        return MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((ulong)((long)b & -(long)b) * DeBruijnSequence) >> 58];
    }
```

The fastest way is to inject Bit Scan Forward (bsf) Bit Instruction to assembly after JIT compiler instead of BitScanForward body, but this requires much more efforts.

Comment: Would you have any URLs to recommend illustrating how one could inject the BSF instruction instead of the body? I understand this is a tricky thing to do, but the performance advantages may overcome the development cost associated to it.

Comment: Performance tested this myself and can confirm that this is almost 2x faster than the other solutions offered

Comment: this answer and all comments here are before the 2020 answer using intrinsics. I suspect that would win.

Answer (score 7):

With .NET Core 3.0 introducing hardware intrinsics, the fastest solution should be

```
ulong value = 18;
ulong result = System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86.Bmi1.X64.TrailingZeroCount(value);
```

Alternatively, the new System.Numerics.Bitoperations methods also use hardware intrinsics:

```
int result2 = System.Numerics.BitOperations.TrailingZeroCount(value);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static UInt64 CountTrailingZeros(UInt64 input)
{
    if (input == 0) return 64;

    UInt64 n = 0;

    if ((input & 0xFFFFFFFF) == 0) { n = 32; input = input >> 32; }
    if ((input & 0xFFFF) == 0) { n = n + 16; input = input >> 16; }
    if ((input & 0xFF) == 0) { n = n + 8; input = input >> 8; }
    if ((input & 0xF) == 0) { n = n + 4; input = input >> 4; }
    if ((input & 3) == 0) { n = n + 2; input = input >> 2; }
    if ((input & 1) == 0) { ++n; }

    return n;
}
```

I changed the answer of Michael D. O'Connor to match Your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static UInt64 CountLeadingZeros(UInt64 input)
{
    if (input == 0) return 64;

    UInt64 n = 1;

    if ((input >> 32) == 0) { n = n + 32; input = input << 32; }
    if ((input >> 48) == 0) { n = n + 16; input = input << 16; }
    if ((input >> 56) == 0) { n = n + 8; input = input << 8; }
    if ((input >> 60) == 0) { n = n + 4; input = input << 4; }
    if ((input >> 62) == 0) { n = n + 2; input = input << 2; }
    n = n - (input >> 63);

    return n;
}
```

I'll bet this'll be faster. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374628/fast-way-of-finding-most-and-least-significant-bit-set-in-a-64-bit-integer).

Comment: That is opposite operation for ulong i = 18 it returns   59, not 2 as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
static Int32 GetLSBPosition(UInt64 v) {
    UInt64 x = 1;
    for (var y = 0; y < 64; y++) {
        if ((x & v) == x) {
            return y;
        }
        x = x << 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While similar to Alexander's answer, this form performs consistently faster, about 46 million operations per second on my machine.

Also, I have written it to be Zero based, but personally I think it should be 1 based, eg:

```
Assert.Equal(0, GetLSBPosition(0));
Assert.Equal(1, GetLSBPosition(1));
Assert.Equal(1, GetLSBPosition(3));
```

Comment: If you did decide you wanted it 1 based, change the for loop to `for (var y = 1; y <= 64; y++)`

Answer (score 1):

As a bit-wise operation, the lowest set bit is:

```
ulong bit = x & ~(x-1);
```

and the original value with the lowest on-bit set to off is:

```
x & (x-1)
```

So to get all the bits that are on:

```
public static void Main()
{
    ulong x = 13;
    while(x > 0)
    {
        ulong bit = x & ~(x-1);
        x = x & (x-1);

        Console.WriteLine("bit-value {0} is set", bit);
    }
}
```

***Output***

```
bit-value 1 is set
bit-value 4 is set
bit-value 8 is set
```

Comment: While this doesn't return the bit position, I still like the algorithm!

Answer (score -1):

The solution with a very fast bit operations. Only unsafe code can be faster.

```
ulong n = 18; // 10010
ulong b = 1;
int p = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    if ((n & b) == b)
    {
        p = i;
        break;
    }
    b = b << 1;
}

Console.WriteLine(p);
```

Comment: I disagree that only unsafe code can be faster.
Your loop runs through each bit-position, one by one.  See my answer for a solution that skips directly to only the bits that are set.