# How to get enum by index with different set values?

Tags: c#

I have an enum with flags setup for my grid system:

```
[Flags]
public enum GridNeighbours
{
    North = 1,
    NorthEast = 2,
    East = 4,
    SouthEast = 8,
    South = 16,
    SouthWest = 32,
    West = 64,
    NorthWest = 128
}
```

But i want to also access them by index so if i want the index of say East, i would get [2] not 4.

Casting to int doesn't do the job as that just gives the flag number which i am not looking for.

Is there a way to do that at all ?

Comment: each flag has only 1 bit set so in this case you just need to use [`BitOperations.TrailingZeroCount((int)enumValue)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.trailingzerocount?view=netcore-3.0)

Comment: @phuclv oh nice :) Do you happen to know the source code of how it is actually done?

Comment: it's an intrinsic that maps directly or indirectly to the machine instruction like x86's TZCNT/BSF or ARM's CLZ and probably a fallback version for architectures without those instructions. Check [dotnet's repo on github](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=org%3Adotnet+TrailingZeroCount&type=Code) and see

Comment: @phuclv the reason i ask is i can't use core for my unity they use .NET 4.x so the class is not available for me :(

Comment: if .NET Core is not available then you must implement it yourself: [What's the quickest way to compute log2 of an integer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8970101/995714), [Fastest implementation of log2(int) and log2(float)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15967240/995714), [Fast way of finding most and least significant bit set in a 64-bit integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31374628/995714)