# C++ to C#, static_cast into enum

Tags: c#, c++, enums, binaryfiles, static-cast

I'm trying to convert a bit of VC 6.0 C++ code to C#. Specifically, I'm parsing through a binary dat file and I've run into a problem converting this bit of code:

```
ar.GetFile()->Read(buf,sizeof(int));  
memmove(&x,buf,4);

pEBMA->before_after = static_cast<enum EBMA_Reserve>(x);
pEBMA->method       = static_cast<enum EBMA_Method>(x >> 4);
```

Here is some related code.

```
struct EBMA_Data *pEBMA = &EBMA_data;

typedef CArray<struct EBMA_Data,struct EBMA_Data&> EBMA_data;

enum EBMA_Reserve
   {EBMA_DONT_RESERVE,
    EBMA_BEFORE,
    EBMA_AFTER
   };

enum EBMA_Method
   {EBMA_CENTER,
    EBMA_ALL_MATERIAL,
    EBMA_FRACTION,
    EBMA_RESERVE
   };


struct EBMA_Data
   {double reserved;
    double fraction;
    enum EBMA_Method method : 4;
    enum EBMA_Reserve before_after : 4;
   };
```

I've read this thread here [Cast int to Enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c), but my code isn't giving me the same results as the legacy program.

Here is some of my code in C#:

```
reserved = reader.ReadDouble();
fraction = reader.ReadDouble();
beforeAfter = (EBMAReserve)Enum.ToObject(typeof(EBMAReserve), x);
method = (EBMAMethod)Enum.ToObject(typeof(EBMAMethod), (x >> 4));
```

I do have an endianness problem so I am reversing the endianness like so.

```
public override double ReadDouble()
        {
            byte[] b = this.ConvertByteArrayToBigEndian(base.ReadBytes(8));
            double d = BitConverter.ToDouble(b, 0);
            return d;
        }
 private byte[] ConvertByteArrayToBigEndian(byte[] b)
        {
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            {
                Array.Reverse(b);
            }

            return b;
        }
```

So then I thought that maybe the endianness issue was still throwing me off so here is another attempt:

```
byte[] test = reader.ReadBytes(8);
Array.Reverse(test);
int test1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
int test2 = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 4);
beforeAfter = (EBMAReserve)test1;
method = (EBMAMethod)test2;
```

I hope I've given enough details about what I'm trying to do.

**EDIT:**

This is how I solved my issue, apparently the values I needed were stored in the first byte of a 4 byte segment in the binary file. This is in a loop.

```
byte[] temp = reader.ReadBytes(4);
byte b = temp[0];

res = (EBMAReserve)(b & 0x0f);
meth = (EBMAMethod)(b >> 4);
```

Comment: Both platforms are little endian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:  It actually looks like the structure size of `EBMA_Data` is 17 bytes.

```
struct EBMA_DATA
{
  double reserved; //(8 bytes)
  double fraction; //(8 bytes)
  enum EBMA_Method method : 4; //(this is packed to 4 bits, not bytes)
  enum EMBA_Reserve before_after : 4; //(this too, is packed to 4 bits)
}
```

so your read code should look something more like this:

```
 EBMA_Data data = new EBMA_Data;
 data.reserved = reader.ReadDouble();
 data.fraction = reader.ReadDouble();
 byte b = reader.ReadByte();
 data.method = (EBMAMethod)(b >> 4);
 data.before_after = (EBMAReserve)(b & 0x0f);
```

---

Not 100% sure, but it looks like the code that does the shift `x >> 4` bytes may be the underlying issue that's being overlooked.  If the `EBMAReserve` is the lower 4 bits of x and `EBMAMethod` is the top 4 bits, maybe this code would work?

```
 EBMAReserve res = (EBMAReserve)(x & 0x0f);
 EBMAMethod meth = (EBMAMethod)(x >> 4);
```

I think that is what the `: 4` means after the enumerations in the struct, it's packing the two enums into the structure as a single byte instead of 2 bytes.

Comment: It didn't work. my EBMAReserve is EBMA_DONT_RESERVE and EBMAMethod is 33554432 when it should be EBMAReserve: 32 and EBMAMethod: EBMA_FRACTION according to the C++ program

Comment: Hey thanks, I got it to work. Your correct that its stored in 17 bytes, but in the binary file that I am working with uses 20 bytes for this information which is looped through.