# c++ enum can compare to integer but not assign from integer?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

enum mode { MODE0=0, MODE1, NUM_MODES};

int main(int args, char ** argv) {
  int i = 1;
  std::cout << (i == MODE0 ? "true" : "false") << "\n";
  std::cout << (i == MODE1 ? "true" : "false") << "\n";
  mode test;
  test = i; // error
}
```

Why is it that the comparison of i to enum values works fine, but I get compilation error when assigning mode test variable to an integer value?

> enum.cc:10:8: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'mode'
>   [-fpermissive]

My question is specifically about why comparison works and assignment doesn't (not how to fix my code) and it has received a couple of good explanations below.

Comment: You have to cast it before assign.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452920/how-to-cast-int-to-enum-in-c

Comment: You would need to `static_cast` it to get it to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using enum says invalid conversion from 'int' to 'type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703743/using-enum-says-invalid-conversion-from-int-to-type)

Answer (score 10):

`MODE0`, `MODE1` and `NUM_MODES` are guaranteed to be convertible to `int` (the underlying type of the `enum`) but the reverse is not true. Not all `int` can be converted to `mode`. For example, what is the matching `mode` for the `int` 42? Simply put, only the implicit conversion from `enum` to `int` is defined, the opposite implicit conversion is not defined.

If you want to convert from `int` to `mode` you can preform a `static_cast` to signal that you are taking the responsibility for the value being converted. Try

```
test = static_cast<mode>(i);
```

You can use strongly typed enumerations by adding the `class` keyword to your `enum` to prevent any implicit casts and to limit the scope of the `enum` value names. The definition would look like `enum class mode { MODE0 = 0, MODE1, NUM_MODES };`. In this case, you must quality the `enum` value names, for example, you would need to use `mode::MODE0` instead of `MODE0`. This has the advantage that it avoids name collisions.

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is a conversion from an enumerated type to `int` but there is no conversion in the opposite direction. For the comparison, `MODE0` gets promoted to `int`. For the assignment, `i` would have to be converted to `mode`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way.  When you do a comparison it doesn't matter if the `int` is not a valid possible value.  If it is not then the comparison will fail and we can go on.  Now when we go and try to assign an `int` to an `enum` you could assign to it a value that isn't mapped to the enum values.  Since we don't want this implicitly happening the conversion is invalid.  If you want to tell the compiler that it is okay, you know what you are doing, then you can cast it like:

```
test = static_cast<mode>(i);
```