# Generic Method to get string from ENUM (by passing int Value)

Tags: c#, generics, enums

i have written a generic method to convert int to Enum String, getting an error. Please Help Thanx.

```
    public static string GetStringEquiValentOFEnumFromString<T>(int enumVal)
        where T : struct
    {
        if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T),enumVal))
        {
            return ((T)enumVal).ToString();  ///Error: Cannot convert type 'int' to 'T'
        }          
        return null;  
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this won't handle combined values of flags enums.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `Enum.ToObject`:

```
public static string GetStringEquiValentOFEnumFromString<T>(int enumVal)
     where T : struct
    {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), enumVal))
        {
            return Enum.ToObject(typeof (T), enumVal).ToString();
        }
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.toobject.aspx

Comment: forgot to give props: pulled it from this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29485/437456

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this error because generic type arguments cannot be constrained to the `enum` type in C#.  Since your constraint only says it has to be a value type the compiler cannot guarantee that `enumVal` will be convertible to `T` and gives a compile time error.

To get around this you can explicitly define the enum type in the function:

```
public static string GetStringFromValue(this MyEnum enum, int val) {
   if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), val)) {
      return ((MyEnum) val).ToString();
   }
   return null;
}
```

Or you can use something like Jon Skeet's [UnconstrainedMelody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) library which rewrites your code at the bytecode level to enforce the `enum` constraint (callable from another assembly).

Comment: there's another wrinkle, which is that the enum might have a smaller type than `int` as its underlying type.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

```
public static string GetStringEquiValentOFEnumFromString<T>(int enumVal) 
    where T : struct 
{ 
    if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T),enumVal)) 
    { 
        return ((T)(object)enumVal).ToString();
    }           
    return null;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public static class StringEnum
    {

```
    public static string GetStringValue(Enum value)
    {
        string output = null;
        Type type = value.GetType();

        FieldInfo fi = type.GetField(value.ToString());
        StringValue[] attr = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringValue), false) as StringValue[];

        if (attr.Length > 0)
        {
            output = attr[0].Value;
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

StringEnum is a class which have (GetStringValue) method to get the string value.

public enum CampaignRequestType { [StringValue("None")] None = 0, [StringValue("Pharmacy Cards")] Pharmacy_Cards = 1,[StringValue("Prospect Campaign")] Prospect_Campaign = 2,[StringValue("Tradeshow/Advertising")] Tradeshow_Advertising = 3 }

its a enum...

string item = StringEnum.GetStringValue((Enumeration.CampaignRequestType)updateRequestStatus.RequestType_Code);

here (Enumeration.CampaignRequestType) is my enumeration and updateRequestStatus.RequestType_Code is data base field int type

i cast int value to enumeration type