# How to convert enum to int

Tags: c#, enums

In C# we can convert an `enum` to an `int` by static typecasting as shown below:

```
int res = (int)myEnum;
```

Is any other way to do this conversion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Shree - That question is int-to-enum, this question is enum-to-int

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are plenty of other ways (including `Convert.ToInt32` as mentioned by acrilige), but a static cast is probably the best choice (as far as readability and performance are concerned)

Comment: Just to add the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#explicit-enumeration-conversions) to the C# 6.0 documentation

Answer (score 10):

Best would be:

```
int res = Convert.ToInt32(myEnum);
```

OR a static cast

```
int res = (int)myEnum;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example enum:

```
public enum Books
{
    cSharp = 4,
    vb = 6,
    java = 9
}
```

Then the code snippet to use would be:

```
Books name = Books.cSharp;
int bookcount = Convert.ToInt32(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

int enumInt = Convert.ToInt32(yourEnum);