# Cast int to Enum while knowing Type

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to cast an int to an Enum, e.g.

```
var result = (MyEnum)value;
```

The Problem is that i only have the Integer and a System.Type.

And this doesn't work:

```
var result = (type)value;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want to cast an `int` to `MyEnum` without knowing what `MyEnum` is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp

Comment: http://tech.pro/tutorial/637/csharp-snippet-tutorial-how-to-get-an-enum-from-a-number

Comment: How are going to use that value if you don't know type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
 Enum.ToObject(type, value);
```

Although I have no idea how you expect to use that result if you don't know what the type is at compile time.

Comment: +1 for writing the same but faster :)