# Assign int value to the custom enum property

Tags: c#, .net

I have property

```
public Enums.CustomEnumProp MyEnum { get; set; }
```

which is of type CustomEnumProp

```
public enum CustomEnumProp { A = 1, B = 2, C = 3}
```

and I need to use passed int value as a user selection and assign it to the `MyEnum` property.

forexampe: is user is selected 2 from combobox then assign this int to the MyEnum.

Thanks

Comment: Move your eyes to the right "Related" bar.

Comment: Kindly use the search before making a new question, as you can see on the right side the very first result is your answer [Cast int to enum in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast the `int` to the `enum`.

```
o.MyEnum = (CustomEnumProp) myInt;
```

You can also use the `Enum.IsDefined` method to check that the `int` is valid.

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(CustomEnumProp), myInt))
   o.MyEnum = (CustomEnumProp) myInt;
```