# How can I use Equal Operator between FontWeights in C#?

Tags: c#, fonts, custom-controls

I have to create a FontWeight property in my CustomControl but it is giving me error in controlling FontWeights. How can I solve it?

Property Registering:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "FontWeight",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(WatermarkTextBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

Property (We can change this property, it is my amateur job):

```
    private int _watermarkFontWeight = 0;

    public int WatermarkFontWeight
    {
        get
        {
            if (watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight == FontWeights.Normal)
            {
                _watermarkFontWeight = 0;
            }
            else if (watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight == FontWeights.SemiBold)
            {
                _watermarkFontWeight = 1;
            }
            else if (watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight == FontWeights.Bold)
            {
                _watermarkFontWeight = 2;
            }
            else if (watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight == FontWeights.ExtraBold)
            {
                _watermarkFontWeight = 3;
            }
            return _watermarkFontWeight;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == 0)
            {
                SetProperty<int>(ref _watermarkFontWeight, value, "FontWeight");
                watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            }
            else if (value == 1)
            {
                SetProperty<int>(ref _watermarkFontWeight, value, "FontWeight");
                watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
            }
            else if (value == 2)
            {
                SetProperty<int>(ref _watermarkFontWeight, value, "FontWeight");
                watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            }
            else if (value == 3)
            {
                SetProperty<int>(ref _watermarkFontWeight, value, "FontWeight");
                watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight = FontWeights.ExtraBold;
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Windows.UI.Text.FontWeight' and 'Windows.UI.Text.FontWeight'
```

Thanks.

Comment: `One is probably an Enumeration vs an Integer` look up how to compare integer value to Enum value `FontWeights.Norma` looks like an `Enum` at first glance

Comment: This link may lend you some possible direction / ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp

Comment: [FontWeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.fontweight) isn't an enumeration, it's a struct so I don't think that would help. EDIT: Tugrul, is this error occurring in your _setter_ or your _getter_?

Comment: This error is appearing in building. @ChrisSinclair

Comment: it is occuring in getter @ChrisSinclair

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell from the [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.fontweight) (which is surprisingly lacking in information and/or I'm having trouble finding detailed decoumentation), `FontWeight` is a `struct` value type that does *not* define an operator for `==` so you can't directly compare them.

However, I think you can compare their underlying wrapped `Weight` value instead:

```
if (watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight.Weight == FontWeights.Normal.Weight)
```

EDIT: I'm not sure if their `Equals` implementation works (again, lovely documentation), but you can create an extension method to give you some half-decent looking syntax:

```
public static bool Equals(this FontWeight weight1, FontWeight weight2)
{
    return weight1.Weight == weight2.Weight;
}
```

Which results in usage:

```
if (watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight.Equals(FontWeights.Normal))
    _watermarkFontWeight = 0;
else if (watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight.Equals(FontWeights.SemiBold))
    _watermarkFontWeight = 1;
else if (watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight.Equals(FontWeights.Bold))
    _watermarkFontWeight = 2;
else if (watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight.Equals(FontWeights.ExtraBold))
    _watermarkFontWeight = 3;
else
    return _watermarkFontWeight;
```

Comment: @TuğrulEmreAtalay: No problem. Honestly, this all seems quite... weird to me the way that particular API is designed. Perhaps there's some reasoning behind it, but I don't know what it is. I've updated my answer to maybe give you a bit more manageable API.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but you can try by comparing after **Converting**  it **To string**..
i.e

```
if (Convert.Tostring(watermarkPassTextBox.FontWeight) == Convert.Tostring(FontWeights.Normal))
        {....}
```