# Get value of enum member by its name?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Say that I have variable whose value (for example, `"listMovie"`) is the name of an `enum` member:

```
public enum Movies
{
    regMovie = 1,
    listMovie = 2 // member whose value I want
}
```

In this example, I would like to get the value `2`. Is this possible? Here is what I tried:

```
public static void getMoviedata(string KeyVal)
{
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TestAppAreana.MovieList.Movies), KeyVal))
    {
        //Can print the name but not value
        ((TestAppAreana.MovieList.Movies)2).ToString(); //list
        Enum.GetName(typeof(TestAppAreana.MovieList.Movies), 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want Enum.Parse / Enum.TryParse

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast int to enum in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Assuming that `KeyVal` is a string representing the name of a certain enum you could do this in the following way:

```
int value = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(TestAppAreana.MovieList.Movies), KeyVal);
```

Comment: but the value is inside a variable i can't do like this TestAppAreana.MovieList.Movies.KeyVal

Comment: it still prints listMovie not the value

Comment: @NavajyothCS it doesn't sound like you're following the instructions here. It should work as he wrote it.

Comment: @bejger yes i tried it but I am getting the same sting as value. I wish I could show you the screen.

Comment: @NavajyothCS: What are you doing with the `int` value once you have it? Are you running it through the same code that you posted, that is: `((TestAppAreana.MovieList.Movies)value).ToString(); Enum.GetName(typeof(TestAppAreana.MovieList.Movies), value);`?

Comment: @bejger Int value is not supporting so I tried this  string str= Enum.Parse(typeof(TestAppAreana.MovieList.Movies), KeyVal).ToString();

Comment: @NavajyothCS: You _must_ include the cast to `int`: `((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(TestAppAreana.MovieList.Movies), KeyVal)).ToString();` Maybe try storing it to a local `int` variable first for easy reading/management.

Comment: Note there's a helpful overload on `Enum.Parse()` that takes a third parameter, `bool ignoreCase = false`.

Answer (score 16):

You want to get the Enum value from the string name. So you can use the [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
int number = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(TestAppAreana.MovieList.Movies), KeyVal)
```

You can also try [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check whether parsing is successful or not.

```
Movies movie;
if (Enum.TryParse(KeyVal, true, out movie))
{

}
```

Comment: it still prints listMovie not the value

Comment: @NavajyothCS are you sure that you are printing `number` variable as in my code, and it is `int` type and can't hold `listMovie` as value.

Comment: Int value is not supporting so I tried this  string str= Enum.Parse(typeof(TestAppAreana.MovieList.Movies), KeyVal).ToString();

Comment: @NavajyothCS **No it will not work**, You have to cast it in `int` to get the number and then you can convert the `int` into the `string`.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
var val= (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(TestAppAreana.MovieList.Movies), KeyVal)
```