# cast int to enum in c# visual studio project

Tags: c#, enums

GetHWTypeName here is defined in int type, I want to cast it to enum type  as XL_HardwareType is of enum type.

```
public string GetHWTypeName(int status)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case (int)XLDefine.XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_CANCARDXL:
            return "CanCardXL";

        case (int)XLDefine.XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_CANCASEXL:
            return "CanCaseXL";

        case (int)XLDefine.XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_VIRTUAL:
            return "Virtual device";

        case (int)XLDefine.XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_CANCARDX:
            return "CanCardX";
        case (int)XLDefine.XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_VN1610:
            return "VN1610";
        // ...
    }
}
```

XL_HardwareType definition is written in this way

```
public enum XL_HardwareType
{
    XL_HWTYPE_NONE = 0,
    XL_HWTYPE_VIRTUAL = 1,
    XL_HWTYPE_CANCARDX = 2,
    XL_HWTYPE_CANAC2PCI = 6,
    XL_HWTYPE_CANCARDY = 12,
    XL_HWTYPE_CANCARDXL = 15,
    XL_HWTYPE_CANCASEXL = 21,
    XL_HWTYPE_CANCASEXL_LOG_OBSOLETE = 23,
    XL_HWTYPE_CANBOARDXL = 25,
    XL_HWTYPE_CANBOARDXL_PXI = 27,
    XL_HWTYPE_VN2600 = 29,
    XL_HWTYPE_VN2610 = 29,
    XL_HWTYPE_VN3300 = 37,
    XL_HWTYPE_VN3600 = 39,
    XL_HWTYPE_VN7600 = 41,
    XL_HWTYPE_CANCARDXLE = 43,
    XL_HWTYPE_VN8900 = 45,
    XL_HWTYPE_VN8950 = 47,
    XL_HWTYPE_VN2640 = 53,
    XL_HWTYPE_VN1610 = 55,
    XL_HWTYPE_VN1630 = 57,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  If you just want to cast it, then cast it?  `return (XLDefine.XL_HardwareType)status` should work.

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp/22830894#22830894 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a straightforward (cast) like this:

```
public string GetHWTypeName(int status)
{
    switch ((XLDefine.XL_HardwareType)status)
    {
        case XLDefine.XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_CANCARDXL:
            return "CanCardXL";

        case XLDefine.XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_CANCASEXL:
            return "CanCaseXL";

        case XLDefine.XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_VIRTUAL:
            return "Virtual device";

        case XLDefine.XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_CANCARDX:
            return "CanCardX";

        case XLDefine.XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_VN1610:
            return "VN1610";
        // ...
    }
}
```

Having said that, it would be better if you can change the signature of `public string GetHWTypeName(int status)` to `public string GetHWTypeName(XLDefine.XL_HardwareType status)` then you don't need the cast at all.

Note that your function as currently defined could be made `static`.