# Foreach enum values without casting

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums

I have to cast enum but I want this to be as generic as possbile. How can I replace the `Cast<XX>()` part with `propertyType`?

```
foreach (var prop in MainType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsEnum))
{
     var x = new { name = prop.Name, values = new List<object>() };

     foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(prop.PropertyType).Cast<XX>())
         x.values.Add(new { p = v.GetAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description, 
                            c = v.GetAttribute<DefaultValueAttribute>().Value });

     o.Add(x);
}


    public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum value) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var type = value.GetType();
        var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
        return type.GetField(name)
            .GetCustomAttributes(false)
            .OfType<TAttribute>()
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }

public enum JobApplicationState : short
{
    [Description("Active")]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(string), "bg-primary text-highlight")]
    Active = 1,
    [Description("Passive")]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(string), "bg-grey text-highlight")]
    Passive = 2,
    [Description("Rejected")]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(string), "bg-danger text-highlight")]
    Rejected = 3,
    [Description("Accepted")]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(string), "bg-success text-highlight")]
    Accepted = 4
}
```

**THIS WORKED!**

```
foreach (MemberInfo m in prop.PropertyType.GetFields())
{
    if (m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() != null && m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultValueAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
             x.values.Add(
                 new
                 {
                     p = ((DescriptionAttribute)m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault()).Description,
                     c = ((DefaultValueAttribute)m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultValueAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault()).Value
        });
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. You don't need to cast it right? I mean, it's a member, which could have attributes.

Comment: Why not use underlying numerical primitive type? (eg. Cast to int)

Comment: don't I need enum type to use GetAttribute method?

Comment: @Mert Nope. Look for `MemberInfo.GetAttribute` on MSDN. A field is a member.

Comment: @PTwr I see that I'm not the only one that's confused. Integers don't have attributes. What I think he intends to do is to get the attribute from a field (e.g. FieldInfo).

Comment: @atlaste Not from a field, but from the values within an `Enum` I guess.

Comment: my bad I should have give an example enum. added to question.

Comment: foreach (MemberInfo m in prop.PropertyType.GetFields()) is worked for me. @atlaste will you create and answer or should I do it myself?

Comment: I'll write something down for you about how it works.

Comment: thank you very much. I wish I worked for you, so much to learn from you guys. I will add what I did in my question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should realize that an enum is nothing more than a named wrapper around an integral value. I've described some details on how enums work here: [Cast int to enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp/22830894#22830894) .

The question here is to get attributes values from an enum. As you might imagine, this question is about getting attributes from the *type*, not about getting attributes from the *value* (there's no such thing). Still, if you call a method like `void Foo<T>(T myEnum)`, the type T will hold all the necessary info, even though 'in real life' the value of myEnum is passed around as an integral type.

From this you can also deduce that you're actually looking for the attributes of the `MemberInfo`'s of `T`, since you're looking for the members of the type (e.g. the enum). Again, all the details are in my post on how enums work. Hence the answer:

```
foreach (MemberInfo m in prop.PropertyType.GetFields())
{
    // use m.GetAttribute(...) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don´t you simply cast to `Enum`:

```
foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(prop.PropertyType).Cast<Enum>())
```

Now you can call your extension-method on every element within the returned list.

```
v.GetAttribute<MyType>()
```