# Getting enum value from dropdown, instead than int value

Tags: c#, enums

I have a dropdown made with the new UI system; I can read the values of the enum, and populate the dropdown without problems.

```
foreach (myclass.myenum the_enum in myclass.myenum.GetValues(typeof(myclass.myenum)))
{
    the_dropdown.options.Add(new Dropown.OptionData() { text = the_enum.ToString()});
}
```

Now, when I read the value though, I get back the int value related to the selected entry. Is there a way to get the value as enum or text; instead than as int?

Comment: Use `Enum.Parse` like this: `(myclass.myenum)Enum.Parse(typeof(myclass.myenum), "Selected text")`

Comment: Is this working in .Net 2.6? I can't see Enum in code completion. It just give me the enum datatype (not capital).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just cast your int value

```
(myclass.myenum)intvalue;
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that this only works when all the enum values are sequential and start with `0` as the first value.

Comment: And I think it would be good if you looked into this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp

Comment: @widi why would a cast to the enum only work for sequential enums? As long as the `intvalue` is a valid value in the enum, this always works.

Comment: @derpirscher yes an valid int value would work, but in this context the int value would be gathered from the dropdown, which would return a value from `0` to `n`. Therefore all the values must be sequential and start with a `0` in order to produce the same results.