# Integer to enum casting in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have an `enum` type with some discontinued values for each `enum`. When I try to cast an `int` value to the `enum` type it returns with multiple `enum` values seperated with the `|` operator. Can anyone explain this logic of how it is cast?

```
enum EnumTest
{
    Test1 = 0,
    Test2 = 1,
    Test3 = 1 << 1,
    Test4 = 1 << 2,
    Test5 = 1 << 12,
    Test6 = 1 << 13,
    Test7 = 1 << 20,
    Test8 = 1 << 22,
    Test9 = 1 << 23,
    Test10 = 1 << 24,
    Test11 = 1 << 25,
    Test12 = 1 << 14,
    Test13 = 1 << 15,
    Test14 = 1 << 16,
    Test15 = 1 << 25,
    Test16 = 1 << 17,
    Test17 = 1 << 18,
    Test18 = 1 << 19,
    Test19 = 1 << 21,
    Test20 = 1 << 26
}

public void method1()
{
    int number=67239937;
    EnumTest e = (EnumTest)number; //output: Test2|Test16|Test20
}
```

Comment: The question isn't a direct dupe but the current accepted answer covers your question.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: The "logic" involved in the cast, incidentally, is really simple -- there is no logic. `e` has the value `67239937` under the covers. The actual mapping to the enum tags is of no concern to the compiler -- enums are really just dolled up integers. It's when the value is interpreted by other pieces of code that the tags come into play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your `enum` is this:

```
enum E {
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 4
    D = 8
}
```

If you translate each value to it's binary value, you get:

```
A = 0001
B = 0010
C = 0100
D = 1000
```

Now let's say you try to convert `12`, `1100` in binary, to this `enum`:

```
E enumTest = (E)12;
```

It will output `C|D`

`|` being the OR operator, `C|D` would mean `0100 OR 1000`, which gives us `1100`, or `12` in decimal.

In your case, it's just trying to find which `enum` combination is equal to `67239937`. This is converted to binary as `100000000100000000000000001`. This then converts to `Test2|Test16|Test20` or `1|(1 << 17)|(1 << 26)`.