# How to print an Enum Value based on an integer user input?

Tags: c#, enums

I've a got an Enum that looks like so:

```
 public enum Month 
    {
        January, February, March,
        April, May, June, July, August,
        Septemper, October, November, December
    };
```

What I need to really do is ask and read from the user a number also like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of the 
month")
int monthValue=int.parse(Console.ReadLine())
```

Lastly I wanna take the monthValue and print the equivalent Enum. 
(e.g april for monthvalue 4)

Comment: just cast it. `(Month)monthValue`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast int to enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I removed my answer due to duplication

Comment: It's quite useful for this type of enum to tell it to start from 1 - then you don't have to worry about forgetting to subtract the value to get the right result  - `public enum Month { January = 1, February, [etc],`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply cast the value to the enum. Don't forget to set initial value for January or take into account that by default enum starts from 0;

Console application will be next:

```
class Program
{

    public enum Month
    {
        January, February, March,
        April, May, June, July, August,
        Septemper, October, November, December
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of the month");

        int monthValue = 0;
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out monthValue);
        Console.WriteLine((Month)monthValue - 1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

in case you don't need temporary variable you could also really convert it to enum. But not forget to set default enum value

```
    public enum Month
    {
        January = 1, February, March,
        April, May, June, July, August,
        Septemper, October, November, December
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of the month");
        var input = Enum.Parse(typeof(Month), Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of casting the integer to an enum, you can use `Enum.Parse` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

The following code prints the name of the month to the console. It uses the static [Enum.GetName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getname?view=netframework-4.7.2)-method for that.

```
string monthName = Enum.GetName(typeof(Month), monthValue - 1);
Console.WriteLine(monthName);
```