# c# use ConsoleColor as int

Tags: c#, console, registry

Is there some way I can use ConsoleColors as the Ints that they are?
Like

```
Console.ForeGroundColor = 10; //ConsoleColor.Green has the Value of 10
```

but i can only use

```
Console.ForeGroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green; //when hovering over "Green" Visual Studio even shows me that Green is 10
```

I managed to find these Color-Ints in the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Console) where the Ints have hexCodes of the colors but no where the name (and i was able to change the value of Green to Orange and back to default but that doesn't matter). So why won't C# or Visual Studio let me use the Ints? Or am I doing something Wrong?

Please try to explain it without using refering to enums. I know, these colornames are enums but i just don't understand enum-conversion yet

Comment: I know, i can make a ConsoleColor[] Array and loop through that.

Comment: @Wayne Phipps yes i have seen this question. But i am relativly new to programming and i have no idea what an enum is

Comment: An **enumeration** defines a common type for a group of related values and enables you to work with those values in a type-safe way within your code.. and yes, I am Jonathan :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Vs 2017: I wrote

```
Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)10;
Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)12;
```

and worked !

Comment: omg... why didn't i think of that. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

`ConsoleColor` is `enum`, not int, And you cannot implicitly convert type `int` to it.

You can use type casting:

```
int x = 10;
Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)x;
```

Or

```
Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)10;
```

[Cast int to enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types