# uwp selectedIndex binding with enum not working twoway

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, combobox, ivalueconverter

so I have **ComboBox** with some items and its **SelectedIndex** is bound **TwoWay** with a property of type **MyTypeEnum** the idea is its selected index value can be set by an **enum to int** converter and when user changes selection on combobox itself then the new **selectedIndex** should update the value it is bound to. it is working fine **OneWay** i.e: from property to SelectedIndex, but not working **reverse** so with breakpoints I have confirmed that **Set** method of my bound property does not execute when I change selection of combobox however the **ConvertBack** method of my converter does execute which is like it should.

I have prepared a minimal and simple code repo to reproduce the issue : https://github.com/touseefbsb/ComboBoxToEnumBug

### Code

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
    <local:IdToIndexConverter x:Key="IdToIndexConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid x:DefaultBindMode="TwoWay">
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyTypeEnum, Converter={StaticResource IdToIndexConverter}}" >
        <ComboBoxItem>item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>item 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>item 3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

**MainViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : Observable
{
    private MyTypeEnum _myTypeEnum = MyTypeEnum.Type1;

    public MyTypeEnum MyTypeEnum
    {
        get => _myTypeEnum;
        set => Set(ref _myTypeEnum, value);
    }
}
```

**Observable**

```
public class Observable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return;
        }

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**MyTypeEnum**

//using byte as parent so that I can start count from 1 instead of 0

```
public enum MyTypeEnum : byte
{
    Type1 = 1,
    Type2,
    Type3
}
```

**Converter**

```
public class IdToIndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => System.Convert.ToInt32(value) - 1;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => ((int)value) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have confirmed that Set method of my bound property does not execute when I change selection of combobox however the ConvertBack method of my converter does execute which is like it should.

Your `ConvertBack` method returns an `int` but it should return an `MyTypeEnum`.

The source property of the view model cannot be set to an `int`, only to a `MyTypeEnum`.

[Cast int to enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I was aslo suspecting that but that isnt the issue bcz the set method usually gives cast exception when something like this happens, but in my case set method never triggers.

Comment: The "set method"? No. This won't even be called if the types don't match. Did you try my suggestion?