# How to select and return a word from an enum

Tags: c#

I want to enter a number and have the console program return the name of the item from an enum

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        enum planets { Mercury = 1, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune};
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int selection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            selection = enum planets;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1} planet(s) from the sun", planets, selection);
            Console.Readkey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast int to enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `planets p = (planets)selection; Console.WriteLine("{0} is planet #{1} from the sun", p, selection);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int selection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1} planet(s) from the sun", (planets)selection, selection);
```