# Can a C# switch expression be used simply to avoid entering break commands?

Tags: c#

I have this code and I am wondering. Could this be changed to use the new C# expression as a way  to eliminate the need for the `break;`

```
switch (reposition)
{
    case (int)POS.First: cIndex = 0; break;
    case (int)POS.Last: cIndex = cIndexLast; break;
    case (int)POS.Prev: cIndex--; break;
    case (int)POS.Next: cIndex++; break;
}
reposition = null;
```

Response for Hogan

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only issue is you can't use `--` and `++`

```
cIndex = (POS)resposition switch
{
   POS.First =>  0,
   POS.Last  => cIndexLast,
   POS.Prev  => cIndex-1,
   POS.Next  => cIndex+1
};
```

re comments about not covered - here we are casting to a POS so all cases in POS are covered.  You should have code before this to check and see that the numeric values of reposition are in the range of pos. (or if you code does this naturally you don't have to worry.)

You can use

```
if (POS.IsDefined(typeof(POS), resposition) { ... }
```

hat tip https://stackoverflow.com/a/29489/215752

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: It's giving me a message saying the switch expression doesn't handle all possible inputs. Do you have a suggestion on how I could fix this? thanks

Comment: What is POS? You seem to no cover every possible enumerator in it.  If you do not want to cover anything else, use underscore to act as default: `_ => throw new NotSupportedException()`

Comment: public enum POS
 {
        First = 0,
        Prev = 1,
        Next = 2,
  Last = 3
 }

Comment: I believe the casting to int is not needed,  maybe that is throwing you off.

Comment: I removed the int but then it gives an error saying a cast is  needed.

Comment: @Alan2 did you cast to POS in the top like I did in my code sample?

Comment: @Hogan - I tried the change you suggested but this time get a different message. I added a screen print to the answer.

Comment: I fixed the typo but still gives the same error. Only solution I have other than ignoring is to add this: _ => throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("Unhandled value: " + reposition.ToString())   This seems to stop the warning from appearing