# Is there a better way to turn an enum into a byte array in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

Declare enum as hex.
I want to compare this enum to the value of a byte array.

An enum declared in hex.

```
enum ByteArrayType
{
    None = 0x0000,

    OK = 0x4F4B,
    NK = 0x4E4B,
}
```

my thoughts

```
byte[] byteOri = { 0x4F, 0x4B };
ByteArrayType typeSelect = ByteArrayType.OK;


//Exception
typeSelect == (ByteArrayType)byteOri

//False
(short)typeSelect == BitConverter.ToInt16(byteOri)

//False
byteOri.Equals(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)typeSelect))
```

I found the 'string -> cast' method.

[How can I cast int to enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/how-can-i-cast-int-to-enum)

```
(ByteArrayType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ByteArrayType), ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(byteOri));
```

but the way i want
It's not a way to turn it into a string.


Is there any other way?

[The full test code is here.](https://github.com/dang-gun/DotNetTest/blob/main/EnumToByteArray/Program.cs)

Comment: What version of .NET? Modern versions support things like `BinaryPrimitives`, so you can write `BinaryPrimitives.WriteUInt16BigEndian(buffer, (UInt16) ByteArrayType.OK)` and `(ByteArrayType) BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16BigEndian(byteOri)` (having `Span` available for such work also improves performance quite a bit). Manually dealing with endianness is tedious.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the reply. 
`(ByteArrayType)BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16BigEndian(byteOri)` works what you want.
Added to test code.